# Projection of the area of parallelogram on coordinate planes

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis

What is the projection of parallelogram build on vectors $d\vec{u}=(du^1,du^2,du^3)$, $d\vec{v}=(dv^1,dv^2,dv^3)$ on coordinate planes?

Comment: It's a (maybe degenerated) parallelogram as well.

Comment: Up to a sign, it is the dot product of $d\vec{u} \times d\vec{v}$ with the unit normal vectors for corresponding coordinate planes.